# How to compare XML file with a CSV file ? robotframework

Tags: xml, csv, robotframework

I have the CSV file in ${data}

Cargar archivo personas 
 [Documentation]      Carga lista de RUTs a validar desde archivo csv
 [Arguments]              ${file_name}

${data}=                 read csv file       ${file_name}
 [return]    ${data}

And i have the XML in ${root}

${RESULT}=       Call Soap Method        PersonalInformation     ${list}      #METODO DEL WEB SERVICE

```
                                                                              #Set Global Variable        ${RESULT}
${xml_result} =          Get Last Received

${xml_unicode} =         Decode Bytes To String       ${xml_result}     UTF-8



#${obj as str}=     Convert To String     ${xml_unicode}
#Log       ${obj as str}
${root} =        Parse XML          ${xml_unicode}
```

How could I do this comparison? Both files contain the same information

Thanks,

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a keyword that does all the logic. This will probably be easiest to do in python.

One strategy is to convert either the xml to csv, or the csv to xml, normalize the data, and then compare.

Another strategy would be to write a loop over the data in the csv file, and for each row you can verify that the data is in the XML by searching for the data using the XML API.